# Expected distance between two vectors that belong to two different Gaussian distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X$, $Y$ be two random variables that follow the Gaussian distributions with mean vectors $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$, and covariance matrices $\Sigma_x$, $\Sigma_y$, respectively. The probability density functions of $X$, $Y$ are given, respectively, by
$$
f_{X}(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\lvert \Sigma_x \rvert^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\exp\Big\{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\mu_x)^\top\Sigma_x^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\mu_x)\Big\},
$$
and
$$
f_{Y}(\mathbf{y})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}\lvert \Sigma_y \rvert^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\exp\Big\{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\mu_y)^\top\Sigma_x^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mu_y)\Big\},
$$
where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\Bbb{R}^n$. We will be thinking of $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$ as "members" of the distributions $X$, $Y$, respectively.

If we have two fixed vectors, say $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$, then the squared Euclidean distance between them would be equal to
$$
\big\lVert \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \big\rVert^2.
$$

If we think about $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{y}$ as above, i.e., as members of $X$, $Y$, respectively, then what would be the **expected value of this distance**?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem **and any attempts you have made to solve it**. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your level of experience.

Comment: Thanks @FlybyNight, I would if I could, but my thoughts are rather vague for the time being... I want some intuition first. I will try to add additional info after a while, if I figure out some approach. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: I would think about the distribution of $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}$ before thinking about the distribution of the square of its norm.  After that, I would recall that covariance matrices can be diagonalized.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy, I will try what you propose and hopefully I will add my results! Everyone else, please have a look too, if you like!

Comment: 4 minutes--and an answer that does not fit in dimension 1...

Comment: @Did, may you please explain your comment? Thanks!

Comment: Sure: you accepted an answer 4 minutes after it was posted, which (i) prevents other users to post alternative answers, (ii) renders dubious that you simply took the time to understand it and check it in depth, (iii) often implies that the answer is modified after it was accepted, as happened here (these remarks apply to any instantaneous acceptance). In addition, in the present case, the answer seems to be wrong.

Comment: You're right... But, why do you say that the answer seems to be wrong?

Comment: Because when both variances are zero, it does not fit. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: By the way, are you asking for $E(\|x-y\|^2)$ or for  $E(\|x-y\|)$? You seem to say both successively...

Comment: @Did, I'm asking for $E(\|x-y\|^2)$... Also, I'm expecting this quantity to have the properties of a metric. This is kinda irrelevant, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and normal $(\mu_X,\Sigma_X)$ and $(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$ respectively, then:

> $$E(\|X-Y\|^2)=\|\mu_X-\mu_Y\|^2+\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y)$$

To show this, note that, by independence, $X-Y$ is normal $(\mu_X-\mu_Y,\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y)$ and that every random variable $Z$ normal $(\mu,\Sigma)$ can be written as $Z=\mu+LU$ where $LL^\top=\Sigma$ and $U$ is standard normal, hence a little bit of matrix calculus should yield the result.

To wit, note that the decomposition $$\|Z\|^2=Z^\top Z=\mu^\top\mu+\mu^\top LU+U^\top L^\top\mu+U^\top L^\top LU,$$ and the fact that $E(U)=0$ and $E(U^\top)=0^\top$ yield $$E(\|Z\|^2)=\mu^\top\mu+E(U^\top L^\top LU).$$
Now, $\mu^\top\mu=\|\mu\|^2$ and $$U^\top L^\top LU=\sum_{k,\ell}(L^\top L)_{k,\ell}U_kU_\ell,\quad E(U_k^2)=1,\quad E(U_kU_\ell)=0\ (k\ne\ell),$$ hence $$E(U^\top L^\top LU)=\sum_{k}(L^\top L)_{k,k}=\mathrm{tr}(L^\top L)=\mathrm{tr}(LL^\top)=\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma).$$ Finally, as desired, $$E(\|Z\|^2)=\|\mu\|^2+\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma).$$

**Remarks:**

- This nowhere uses the explicit forms of the densities. As a matter of fact,  when solving problems about normal random variables, a useful principle is to avoid as much as possible to manipulate the gaussian densities themselves. Instead, write each $(\mu,\Sigma)$ normal random variable as $\mu+LU$ with $LL^\top=\Sigma$, as we did, and proceed with the standard normal $U$.
- The mapping $(x,y)\mapsto\|x-y\|^2$ is not a metrics, only $(x,y)\mapsto\|x-y\|$ is.

Comment: Let me hope that you took the time to read carefully and to check every step of the proof, this time.

Comment: Yes, @Did, I did! Thank you very much! Now, I'm trying to find out what the expected value of $\|x-y\|$ is, but I don't know how to handle the square root. That is, taking your approach, I would say that $\|Z\|=\sqrt{Z^{\top}Z}$, and thus $E(\|Z\|)=E(\sqrt{Z^{\top}Z})$, but how do I need to continue? May you include this case, too? Thanks again!

Comment: Without the square, there might not exist any formula as convenient as the one above. Already in dimension $1$, one gets the not-so inspiring identity $$E(|Z|)=\sigma A(\mu/\sigma),\qquad A(x)=\varphi(x)+x(2\Phi(x)-1).$$

Comment: Hmm, I see, thanks!

Comment: one more question: While I can show that $\|\mu_X-\mu_Y\|^2$ is negative-definite, I am not sure if this is also feasible for the case of $\|\mu_X-\mu_Y\|^2 + tr(\Sigma_X+\Sigma_Y)$. Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: Negative definite? I am afraid I cannot figure what you mean to ask.

Comment: I mean that it must be $\sum_{i,i}^{m}c_ic_jf(x_i,x_j)\leq0$, for all $m\in\Bbb{N}$, $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}\in\Bbb{R}^n$, $\{C_1,\ldots,C_m\}\in\Bbb{R}$, with $\sum_i^m c_i=0$.In our case, of course, is $x_i^{\sigma}=(x_j,\Sigma_i)$ and $x_j^{\sigma}=(x_j,\Sigma_j)$ instead...

Comment: For which function $f$?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to mention it.. Let $f\colon(\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n)\times(\Bbb{R}^n\times\Bbb{S}_{++}^n)\to \Bbb{R}$, where $\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ is the space of $n\times n$ spd matrices (covariance matrices). That is, $f(x_i^{\sigma},x_j^{\sigma})=\| x_i -x_j \|^2+\operatorname{trace}(\Sigma_x+\Sigma_y)$.

Comment: I see no reason to think this should be negative-definite, there are probably some easy counterexamples.

Comment: I was hoping in finding some conditions under which this is negative-definite, but indeed it isn't in general.

Answer (score 2):

If $x,y$ are independent, and thus, uncorrelated, then $p(x,y)$ is their joint probability distribution, which is Gaussian again, with mean: $[\mu_x,\mu_y]^T$ and covariance $\text{diag}\{\Sigma_x,\Sigma_y\}$ (dimensions are $2N\times2N$).

Then, $E_{p(x,y)}[\|x-y\|^2]=E_{p(x,y)}[\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2-2x^Ty]=\mu_x^T\mu_x+\mu_y^T\mu_y+\operatorname{trace}{(\Sigma_x+\Sigma_y)}$, since $x,y$ are independent.

--->The expectation, of course, is taken with respect to the joint probability of the two vectors. Thus, $x,y$ are considered members of the joint, instead of their respective distributions, in order the question to have meaning.

(Edit: as it was pointed out in the comments, the mistake above is the assumption that $E_{p(x,y)}[x^Ty]=0$. It is rather
$E_{p(x,y)}[x^Ty]=\mu_x^T\mu_y$, 
which makes the overall expected value equal to:

$E_{p(x,y)}[\|x-y\|^2]=||\mu_x-\mu_y||^2+\operatorname{trace}{(\Sigma_x+\Sigma_y)}$

Edit (cont'd): my approach is based on the formulas used for calculating the expectation of inner and outer products with respect to a distribution:
$E[zz^T]=\operatorname{trace}{(\mu_z\mu_z^T+\Sigma_z)}$, where $z$ follows $N(\mu_z,\Sigma_z)$)

Edit 2: Correction: $\Sigma_z^{-1}$ has been replaced by  $\Sigma_z$ (and the same for $x,y$).

You are welcome,

Giannis.

Comment: Where does the formula in the RHS come from? Without any explanation, this is hard to guess.

Comment: Thanks Giannis, but, as @Did did point out, could you give more details on where the RHS came from? It seems to be wrong, but I cannot find the expected value of the quantity $-2x^Ty$...

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake, I overestimated my skills and posted the answer in a very short time. Did's solutions seems fine to me.

Comment: Still some mistakes in the edited version: every $\Sigma^{-1}$ should read $\Sigma$. (But I still fail to understand where the formulas come from, it is as if you answered that the answer is what it is because we *know* that it is what it is...)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that the identity that @Did points out has **nothing** to do with the Gaussian distribution and would hold true for *any* uncorrelated random vectors $X,Y$. Rather it is a simple consequence of the [bias-variance decomposition](http://theanalysisofdata.com/notes/estimators1.pdf) of the mean squared error:

$$E[\|\hat\theta-\theta\|^2]=\|E[\hat\theta]-\theta\|^2+ tr(V(\hat\theta)),$$

where $\hat \theta$ is some random vector thought of as an estimator for parameter $\theta$. The identity @Did mentions is the case where $\hat\theta=X-Y,\theta=0,$ and $X\sim N(\mu_X,\Sigma_X),Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\Sigma_Y)$ are uncorrelated (so that the variance of the difference is the sum of their variances).

---

Here is a simple proof to convince you. First, recall some properties:

1. $V(X)=E[XX']-E[X]E[X']$
2. $tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B)$
3. $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$.

Then we have

$$\begin{align}tr(V(\hat\theta))&=tr(V(\hat\theta-\theta))\\
&=tr(E[(\hat\theta-\theta)(\hat\theta-\theta)']-E[\hat\theta-\theta]E[(\hat\theta-\theta)'])\quad (1)\\
&=tr(E[(\hat\theta-\theta)(\hat\theta-\theta)'])-tr(E[\hat\theta-\theta]E[(\hat\theta-\theta)'])\quad (2)\\
&=tr(E[(\hat\theta-\theta)'(\hat\theta-\theta)])-tr(E[\hat\theta-\theta]'E[\hat\theta-\theta])\quad (3)\\
&=E[\|\hat\theta-\theta\|^2]-\|E[\hat\theta]-\theta\|^2\\
\implies E[\|\hat\theta-\theta\|^2]&=\|E[\hat\theta]-\theta\|^2+ tr(V(\hat\theta))& \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

For the record, both the result found by @Did and the bias-variance decomposition mentioned by @Golden_Ratio are consequences of a basic identity.

---

**Claim:** If random vector $W$ has mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, then
$$E(W^TW)=\mu^T\mu + \operatorname{tr}(\Sigma).$$

**Proof:**
$$
E(W^TW)-\mu^T\mu\stackrel{(a)}=E[(W-\mu)^T(W-\mu)]
\stackrel{(b)}=\sum_{i} E[(W_i-\mu_i)^2]
\stackrel{(c)}=\sum_i \operatorname{Var}(W_i)
\stackrel{(d)}=\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma).$$
Step (a) is matrix algebra; (b) is the inner product of a vector with itself; (c) is the definition of variance for a random variable; (d) follows from inspection of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Alternatively, argue
$E(W-\mu)^T(W-\mu)=\operatorname{tr}(\Sigma)$ by using the trick $v^Tv=\operatorname{tr}(v^Tv)=\operatorname{tr}(vv^T)$, valid for column vectors $v$.

---

To obtain @Did's result, put $W:=X-Y$; to obtain the bias-variance decomposition, put $W:=\hat\theta-\theta$.