# Expected squared distance between two jointly gaussian distributed random variables (dependent, with covariance)

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

This is question basically asks for a generalization of the answer to this question:
[Expected distance between two vectors that belong to two different Gaussian distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917292/expected-distance-between-two-vectors-that-belong-to-two-different-gaussian-dist) . The difference here is that I know my variables have covariance.

If I have two $N$-dimensional random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are jointly gaussian distributed and not independent, i.e. the combined vector $Z=[X_0,...,X_N,Y_0,...,Y_N]$ is distributed according to $Z\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Z, \Sigma_Z)$, where

$\Sigma_Z = \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_X & \Sigma_{XY}\\ \Sigma_{YX} & \Sigma_Y\end{bmatrix}$,

and $\Sigma_{XY}$, $\Sigma_{YX}$ are not just zero matrices.

What is the expected value of the squared euclidean distance between $X$ and $Y$?

I would highly appreciate help on this one. Also, please let me know if I can ask the question in a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that everything is $0$ mean.

You can reexpress the distance as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\| X-Y \|^2] &= \mathbb E[(X-Y)^T(X-Y)]\\
&= \mathbb E[X^TX] + \mathbb E[Y^TY]-2 \mathbb E[X^TY]
\end{align*}
To treat terms like $\mathbb E[X^T X]$ you can use the trick $X^T X = \text{Tr}(X^TX) = \text{Tr}(XX^T)$ this together with the fact that trace is linear yelds
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X^TX] &= \text{Tr} (\Sigma_X )\\
\mathbb E[Y^TY] &= \text{Tr} (\Sigma_Y )\\
\mathbb E[X^TY] &= \text{Tr} (\Sigma_{YX} )
\end{align*}
So in the end you obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\| X-Y \|^2] &= \text{Tr} (\Sigma_X ) + \text{Tr} (\Sigma_Y ) -2 \text{Tr} (\Sigma_{YX} )
\end{align*}

---

If $X$ now have mean $\mu_X$ and $Y$ have mean $\mu_Y$, then
\begin{align*}
&\| X-Y \|^2\\=& \| (X-\mu_X)-(Y-\mu_Y)+\mu_X-\mu_Y \|^2\\
=& \| (X-\mu_X)-(Y-\mu_Y) \|^2 + 2 \langle (X-\mu_X)-(Y-\mu_Y),\mu_X-\mu_Y\rangle +\| \mu_X-\mu_Y \|^2
\end{align*}
taking the expectation of this, the second term is $0$ since both $X-\mu_X$ and $Y-\mu_Y$ have mean $0$. So we get that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\| X-Y \|^2] &= \text{Tr} (\Sigma_X ) + \text{Tr} (\Sigma_Y ) -2 \text{Tr} (\Sigma_{YX} ) + \| \mu_X-\mu_Y \|^2
\end{align*}

Comment: Whoa, that was quick! Thanks a lot @P.Quinton, the derivation makes sense and I also tested it numerically. You are my hero!
Edit: I would also upvote the answer, but I can't yet, due to too little reputation.

Comment: This holds for any random variables X and Y, right? In other words, you haven't used OP's assumption that X and Y are jointly gaussian.

Comment: Yes indeed, as long as you know the traces of the covariance and the means then you can do that.