# Expected value of the exponential of negative Euclidian distance between two vectors drawn from Normal distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $\mathbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}_x, \mathbf{\Sigma}_x)$ and $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}_y, \mathbf{\Sigma}_y)$ be two $K$ dimensional random vectors drawn from different Multivariate Normal distributions. What is the expected value of the exponential of the negative squared Euclidian distance between these two vectors, i.e., $\mathbb{E}[\exp(-||\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}||_2^2)]$? This post ([Expected distance between two vectors that belong to two different Gaussian distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917292/expected-distance-between-two-vectors-that-belong-to-two-different-gaussian-dist) ) computes the expectation without the exponential term. But I could not extend it.

Update:

Based on the comments, I derived the expectation assuming the covariances are diagonal as follows:

Let $z = x - y$, then $z \sim N(m, \Sigma)$, where $m = m_x - m_y$ and $\Sigma = \Sigma_x + \Sigma_y$. In the diagonal case, the components are independent and component $i$ is denoted as $z_i \sim N(m_i, \sigma_i^2)$.

Then, the expectation becomes:

$$E[e^{-||z||_2^2}] = \prod_{i=1}^K E[e^{-z_i^2}] $$

If we reparametrize by using $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$ as $z_i = m_i + \sigma_i \epsilon$, we can compute the expectation for component $i$ as follows:

$$ E[e^{-z_i^2}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{-(m_i + \sigma_i \epsilon)^2} e^{-\epsilon^2/2}d\epsilon $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-m_i^2} \int e^{-\sigma_i^2 \epsilon^2 - 2m_i\sigma_i \epsilon - \epsilon_i^2/2 } d\epsilon$$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-m_i^2} \int  e^{-\frac{1}{2} (\epsilon^2(1 + 2\sigma_i^2) + 4m_i\sigma_i \epsilon) }d\epsilon $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-m_i^2 } \int e^{ -\frac{1+2\sigma_i^2}{2} \big[ (\epsilon + \frac{2m_i\sigma_i}{1+2\sigma_i^2})^2 - \frac{4m_i^2\sigma_i^2}{(1+2\sigma_i^2)^2}\big] }d\epsilon $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\sigma_i^2}} e^{-m_i^2 + \frac{2m_i^2\sigma_i^2}{1+2\sigma_i^2}} $$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\sigma_i^2}} e^{ \frac{-m_i^2}{1+2\sigma_i^2}} $$

I validated the result using simulation. I would appreciate it if someone can suggest how to extend it to the non-diagonal case.

Comment: One small reduction: $x-y \sim N(m_x-m_y, \Sigma_x + \Sigma_y)$ so it suffices to consider $z \sim N(m, \Sigma)$ and ask what $E[e^{\|z\|_2^2}]$ is.

Comment: Next reduction: You can probably (?) assume that $\Sigma$ is diagonal by applying an orthogonal change of variables. This should allow you to reduce to the 1D case in which a formula is probably already known (?).

Comment: Can you give me a bit more detail on how to use the orthogonal change of variable if the covariances are full?

Comment: Are $\  \mathbf{x}\ $ and $\ \mathbf{y}\ $ independent?  To get $\ \Sigma_z=\Sigma_x+\Sigma_y\ $ you need them to be at least uncorrelated $\big($otherwise $\ \Sigma_z=$$\Sigma_x+$$\Sigma_y-$$2\Sigma_{xy}\ \big)$.  Also, is $\  (\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})\ $ multivariate normal (which you appear to be assuming for the diagonal case, but which does not necessarily follow from the separate normality of $\  \mathbf{x}\ $ and $\ \mathbf{y}\ $ )?  Without that assumption, I don't believe any answer is possible.